# Append a DataFrame as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following piece of code:

```
rev = input(rev: )
def ds():
    data = pd.read_excel(r'H:\sysfile.xls', skiprows=2)
    dataset1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Col_1', 'Col_2', 'Col_3', 'Col_4'])
    dataset2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Col_5'])
    dataset2['Col_5'] = dataset2['Col_5'].fillna(rev)

ds()
```

Col_5 is an existing Column in the `xls` File. I want to give every cell in the column the input from `rev`
If I `print()` the `dataset1` i get the content of the existing DataFrame (read from the `xls`-File):

```
   A    B    C
0  x    y    z
1  x    y    z
2  x    y    z
```

Now I want to write the userinput from `rev=input()` into DataFrame `dataset2` and append it to `dataset 1`.

INPUT:

```
>>>rev: h
```

Should become this (`dataset2`):

```
    D
0   h
1   h
2   h
```

and appand to `dataset1`:

```
   A    B    C    D
0  x    y    z    h
1  x    y    z    h
2  x    y    z    h
```

I need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you managed already to fill the dataset2 with the user input, what you need is to join both datasets:

```
dataset1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], 'B': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'], 'C': ['z', 'z', 'z', 'z']})

Out[5]: 
   A  B  C
0  X  Y  z
1  X  Y  z
2  X  Y  z
3  X  Y  z

dataset2 = pd.DataFrame({'D': ['h', 'h', 'h', 'h']})

Out[8]: 
   D
0  h
1  h
2  h
3  h
```

At this point you need to join them:

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, sort=False)

Out[10]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  X  Y  z  h
1  X  Y  z  h
2  X  Y  z  h
3  X  Y  z  h
```

You can read it in here for further details:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: yes that's it. Thanks a lot.  I misunderstood the documentation but now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Transpose of your data frame and add that column as a row.

After adding that row you can use Transpose again to transform your data frame to its normal form